# Error during spring xml parsing

Tags: spring, dtd

I am using one spring xml file in my web application where I mentioned doctype is as public. Here is my code present at the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
</beans>
```

This xml is running successfully in my local machine where i am using tomcat server. But the same xml is not running linux server where i am using jboss 5.0.1. It is throwing the error as UnknownHost exception : "www.springframework.org" during starting the server.

Any idea where exactly i am missing something?
Thanx Amit

Comment: There's a good chance the DTD you're looking for is incorrect; if the library doesn't add the location to a list of known DTDs some parsers will go out to the internet to try to fetch it. That's a really old version of Spring, too.

Comment: thanks Dave for ur quick reply. Do that dtd needs to be present in the META-INF folder of the spring jar? And let me tell you, I am using that spring xml for very specific purpose and it is fulfilling by thats why i am using this version of spring.

Comment: I'm not really sure. That looks like the correct DTD, though, now that I see it on my laptop.

Comment: any ways it is working now. I added the dtd inside the spring-beans.dtd containing folder of the spring jar. thanks